# Install iTunes on Ubuntu

Tags: itunes

I've always been an Ubuntu lover, but the only thing that holds me back from installing ubuntu on my laptop is iTunes. I have an iPad and an iPod touch and managing them without itunes is almost next to impossible, mainly because of ios upgrades.

Is there any way out?

Comment: AFAIK you do not need iTunes to upgrade iOS on an iPad (since iOS 5)

Comment: I tried installing it through Play On Linux and it did not work for me. Going to try the VM suggestion from - http://www.ubuntuka.com/itunes-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 2):

After extensive testing, I was unable to get iTunes Music Store to work - at all. Complete fail. The best I could achieve was to get the music player to work.

Frustrated, I went looking for a decent alternative. Enter Google Music...

It might be worth a look-see because it'll work no matter what device or OS you use, because it's web-based.

Being web-based, it offers way better features, like the choice of multiple downloads of music purchased and/or streaming it from anywhere from the cloud. You can also upload your music to the cloud too - upto 20,000 tracks for free. The Store music is high-quality (320kbps) mp3, which is playable on many players available today.

Sorry, not meaning it to sound like an advert, but it's really that good!

Baldrick.

Comment: I was prompted by this to try Google Music, and I'd urge other readers not to get their expectations up too high.  Seen as a streaming music service with some cloud storage on the side, it's pretty good.  **If you come to it wanting a replacement for iTunes, for storing and managing your music library, you will be disappointed.** The biggest issue is that it's difficult to upload individual songs or selentions; you can only upload an entire library, which is (inevitably) very slow, and happens in slightly unpredictable order.  Also quality is limited, to a degree audible on most headphones.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PlayonLinux from Software Centre and then install itunes on ubuntu using executeable(.exe) intaller of windows. Windows application will run on ubuntu using wine....

Comment: Do you manage to synchronize iDevices using this ?

Comment: @smonff does synchronization require USB? If it does, it definitely won't work, because Wine *(and playonlinux being a wrapper around it)* doesn't have a wrapper around a Windows USB API. [Multiple years ago someone tried hooking it up](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2015-April/107455.html), but probably couldn't finish, for whatever reasons.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thanx