# Connect iPhone to ITunes on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: internet, iphone

I was able to install iTunes version 12.9.03 (64bit) and it's up and running with no problem. All my music and other downloads from iTunes appear and it is apparently working flawlessly on Ubuntu 22.04, but it cannot recognize my iPhone. This  making the software pointless.

Is there any way to fix this? I believe it is a software compatibility issue because my iPhone is being recognize by Ubuntu and the iPhone folders and media are accessible in Ubuntu.

I already installed/updated the libraries, as well as iFuse.

Thanks, and cheers!

Comment: It doesn't work. You would have to run Windows in a virtual machine. https://askubuntu.com/q/245554/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble should we vote to close as a duplicate?